# WCF Service wont deserialize int[] or List<int>

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, deserialization, datacontract

My WCF service works fine for JSON but when I send XML I get the below error.

> There was an error deserializing the object of type GetChecksObj. End element 'CheckNumbers'
>   from namespace '' expected. Found element 'int' from namespace ''.
>   Line 4, position 10.

I changed the `public int[] CheckNumbers;` to `public List<int> CheckNumbers;` to see if it would make any difference and it doesn't give an error anymore but the deserialized list is empty.

```
[DataContract(Namespace="")]
public class GetChecksObj
{
    [DataMember(Name = "CheckNumbers", EmitDefaultValue = true, IsRequired = true, Order = 1)]
    public int[] CheckNumbers;

    [DataMember(Name = "BusinessDate", EmitDefaultValue = true, IsRequired = true, Order = 2)]
    public DateTime BusinessDate;

    [DataMember(Name = "LocationID", EmitDefaultValue = true, IsRequired = true, Order = 3)]
    public int LocationID;
}
```

The XML which I am sending is as below:

```
<GetChecksObj xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="">
    <CheckNumbers>
        <int>1001</int>
        <int>1002</int>
        <int>1003</int>
    </CheckNumbers>
    <BusinessDate>2014-04-09T00:00:00+01:00</BusinessDate>
    <LocationID>123456</LocationID>
</GetChecksObj>
```

This is my contract

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/GetChecks", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
Check[] GetChecks(GetChecksObj getChecksReq);
```

It doesn't seem to like an array of integers but I cant figure out why. 
Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried it with EmitDefaultValue = False for the int[] CheckNumbers ?

Comment: No but EmitDefaultValue just defines whether it should serialize a value if the property is NULL. But its not null so it wont make a difference.

Comment: Try `BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped`.